# When activating a Steam download key, do I get to see what it contains first?

Tags: steam

I've received a complimentary Steam download key from Ubisoft as a compensation for a problem with a different game I have purchased.

Unfortunately Ubisoft did not write what the download key contains, they only mention 'unlocking additional content'.

I'd like to see what the key contains *before* actually consuming it. When entering the key into Steam, does Steam tell me what the key contains, or does it just immediately use the activation key without giving me another chance to cancel the process?

Comment: Ubisoft better give up on their platform and gift every user with Steam keys for owned on Uplay games. Same for Origin.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From my own experience and a quick web search: No, it will only tell you what a key is for after activating it.

Comment: +1 Having activated many keys before, I can confirm this.  If you already own that particular game, though, it won't activate the key, but will still tell you what it's for.